# Sceneform - How to fix leaking SceneView?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform, leakcanary

I've been using `SceneView` for loading 3D models for almost a year now but I never understood what caused this leak. I would implement LeakCanary, but just this one leak because I couldn't figure out how to fix the problem.

But now I want to get to the bottom of the issue and try to fix it. I've tested it on two versions of `Sceneform` -- `1.15.0` and the last version before being deprecated by Google `1.17.1` and the issue happens on both.

The leak happens when you load a model using `SceneView` in an `Activity` or `Fragment` (I've tried both) and you "exit the app" by doing the `System home navigation` or switching to a different app via the `Recent tasks list`.

[image]

**The logs for the leak:**

```
┬───
│ GC Root: System class
│
├─ android.app.ActivityThread class
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
│    ↓ static ActivityThread.sCurrentActivityThread
├─ android.app.ActivityThread instance
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking)
│    mInitialApplication instance of android.app.Application
│    ↓ ActivityThread.mActivities
├─ android.util.ArrayMap instance
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ ArrayMap.mArray
├─ java.lang.Object[] array
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ Object[].[1]
├─ android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord instance
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking)
│    activity instance of com.example.a3dmodeltester.MainActivity with
│    mDestroyed = false
│    ↓ ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord.activity
├─ com.example.a3dmodeltester.MainActivity instance
│    Leaking: NO (SceneView↓ is not leaking and Activity#mDestroyed is false)
│    mApplication instance of android.app.Application
│    mBase instance of android.app.ContextImpl
│    ↓ MainActivity.sceneView
├─ com.google.ar.sceneform.SceneView instance
│    Leaking: NO (View attached)
│    View is part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
│    View.mID = R.id.sceneview
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    mContext instance of com.example.a3dmodeltester.MainActivity with
│    mDestroyed = false
│    ↓ SceneView.renderer
│                ~~~~~~~~
├─ com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Renderer instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 2.9 kB in 38 objects
│    ↓ Renderer.viewAttachmentManager
│               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ViewAttachmentManager instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 2.2 kB in 19 objects
│    ↓ ViewAttachmentManager.frameLayout
│                            ~~~~~~~~~~~
╰→ android.widget.FrameLayout instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because android.widget.
​     FrameLayout received View#onDetachedFromWindow() callback)
​     Retaining 1.9 kB in 15 objects
​     key = 10550463-895e-443a-898f-11c5131da209
​     watchDurationMillis = 5165
​     retainedDurationMillis = 157
​     View not part of a window view hierarchy
​     View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
​     View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
​     mContext instance of com.example.a3dmodeltester.MainActivity with
​     mDestroyed = false

METADATA

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 27
Build.MANUFACTURER: Google
LeakCanary version: 2.7
App process name: com.example.a3dmodeltester
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=892,misses=24408,hitRate=3%]
RandomAccess[bytes=1232425,reads=24408,travel=6462427001,range=8963521,size=1161
0814]
Heap dump reason: 1 retained objects, app is not visible
Analysis duration: 5411 ms
```

**Reproducing the leak:**

Last version before deprecation:

```
 implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.17.1'
 debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.7'
```

I have also tried it with `1.15.0`

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <com.google.ar.sceneform.SceneView
        android:id="@+id/sceneview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`MainActivity` (have also tested on a fragment)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final Vector3   STARTING_CAMERA_POSITION = new Vector3(0f, 1f, 3f);
    private              SceneView sceneView;
    private              Node      node;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sceneView = findViewById(R.id.sceneview);
        Scene scene = sceneView.getScene();
        node = new Node();
        scene.addChild(node);

        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this, Uri.parse("Andy.sfb"))
                .build()
                .thenAccept(renderable -> node.setRenderable(renderable))
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable -> {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to load Renderable.", throwable);
                            return null;
                        });
        Camera camera = scene.getCamera();
        camera.setWorldPosition(STARTING_CAMERA_POSITION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sceneView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            sceneView.resume();
        } catch (CameraNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sceneView.destroy();
    }
}
```

The `.sfb` file

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NchJ2NGNM7NZzRZkq4fewALc7m4dnGG3/view?usp=sharing

To reproduce press the `Home` or `Recent task list` button while `SceneView` is running

[image]

I've also tested it with only just the `SceneView`, but it leaks as well.

[image]

How would I fix this leak?

I've also tested it on multiple APIs, emulators, and real devices and it happens on all of them.

Comment: do you fix this issue? or tried to move to 1.16?

Comment: @YehezkielL Try my answer below. It fixes the leak for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried these options to stop the leak but they do not do anything:

```
Scene scene = sceneView.getScene();
scene = null;
sceneView = null;
sceneView.destroy();
Renderer.destroyAllResources();
Renderer.reclaimReleasedResources();
```

This however, fixes the leak for me:

Removing the `sceneView.pause();` from

```
@Override
public void onPause()
```

stops the leak when doing a System home navigation or switching to a different app via the Recent tasks list. (The question in the OP)

Adding `sceneView.pause();` to

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
```

Prevents a leak when the activity or fragment is destroyed.

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sceneView.pause(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

as you already said is the last version 1.17.1
A few enthusiasts are working on a [maintained version](https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android). Maybe this version fixes your Memory Leak issue.